# unknown number of parameters in bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What do you guys do when you don't know the number of parameters that you are going to receive?

for example:

```
if($a==1) $filter.=" AND u.name = ?";
if($b==1) $filter.=" AND u.address = ?";
if($c==1) $filter.=" AND u.age = ?";
if($d==1) $filter.=" AND u.city = ?";
ETC...

$stmt->prepare("SELECT id
                FROM users u
                WHERE u.cp = ?
                ".$filter);

$stmt->bind_param("i", $cp);
```

And now? if you are receiving `$a = 1` you will get an error because you are only passing 1 parameter on the `bind_param`. So you don't know if you are going to receive 1, 2, 3 or 4 params and I don't want to make a lot of `IF` or I must use a loop to count the number of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to manage the list of arguments (type and value) as you add the conditions. This means you need to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to pass the list of values to `bind_param`.

Basically, in each of your `if` statements, not only add the condition, but also add the parameter type (e.g. `$types .= 'i'`) and the parameter (e.g. `$args[]=$arg`).

You'll find a good example on how to do this in this comment of the `bind_param` documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#109256